# scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier probabilistic prediction vs majority vote

Tags: scikit-learn

In the documentation of scikit-learn in [section 1.9.2.1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests) (excerpt is posted below), why does the implementation of random forest differ from the original paper by Breiman? As far as I'm aware, Breiman opted for a majority vote (mode) for classification and an average for regression (paper written by Liaw and Wiener, the maintainers of the original R code with citation below) when aggregating the ensembles of classifiers.

1. Why does scikit-learn use probabilistic prediction instead of a majority vote?
2. Is there any advantage in using probabilistic prediction?

The section in question:

> In contrast to the original publication [B2001], the scikit-learn
>   implementation combines classifiers by averaging their probabilistic
>   prediction, instead of letting each classifier vote for a single
>   class.

Source: Liaw, A., & Wiener, M. (2002). Classification and Regression by randomForest. R news, 2(3), 18-22.

Answer (score 2):

This question has now been [answered on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127077/random-forest-probabilistic-prediction-vs-majority-vote/148610#148610).  Included here for reference:

> Such questions are always best answered by looking at the code, if
>   you're fluent in Python.
>
> `RandomForestClassifier.predict`, at least in the current version
>   0.16.1, predicts the class with highest probability estimate, as given by `predict_proba`. ([this
>   line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.16.1/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L465))
>
> The documentation for `predict_proba` says:
>
> > The predicted class probabilities of an input sample is computed as the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
> >     class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the
> >     same class in a leaf.
>
> The difference from the original method is probably just so that
>   `predict` gives predictions consistent with `predict_proba`. The
>   result is sometimes called "soft voting", rather than the "hard"
>   majority vote used in the original Breiman paper. I couldn't in quick
>   searching find an appropriate comparison of the performance of the two
>   methods, but they both seem fairly reasonable in this situation.
>
> The `predict` documentation is at best quite misleading; I've
>   submitted [a pull
>   request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4640) to
>   fix it.
>
> If you want to do majority vote prediction instead, here's a function
>   to do it. Call it like `predict_majvote(clf, X)` rather than
>   `clf.predict(X)`. (Based on `predict_proba`; only lightly tested, but
>   I think it should work.)
>
> ```
> from scipy.stats import mode
> from sklearn.ensemble.forest import _partition_estimators, _parallel_helper
> from sklearn.tree._tree import DTYPE
> from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
> from sklearn.utils import check_array
> from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
>
> def predict_majvote(forest, X):
>     """Predict class for X.
>
>     Uses majority voting, rather than the soft voting scheme
>     used by RandomForestClassifier.predict.
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>         The input samples. Internally, it will be converted to
>         ``dtype=np.float32`` and if a sparse matrix is provided
>         to a sparse ``csr_matrix``.
>     Returns
>     -------
>     y : array of shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]
>         The predicted classes.
>     """
>     check_is_fitted(forest, 'n_outputs_')
>
>     # Check data
>     X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")
>
>     # Assign chunk of trees to jobs
>     n_jobs, n_trees, starts = _partition_estimators(forest.n_estimators,
>                                                     forest.n_jobs)
>
>     # Parallel loop
>     all_preds = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=forest.verbose,
>                          backend="threading")(
>         delayed(_parallel_helper)(e, 'predict', X, check_input=False)
>         for e in forest.estimators_)
>
>     # Reduce
>     modes, counts = mode(all_preds, axis=0)
>
>     if forest.n_outputs_ == 1:
>         return forest.classes_.take(modes[0], axis=0)
>     else:
>         n_samples = all_preds[0].shape[0]
>         preds = np.zeros((n_samples, forest.n_outputs_),
>                          dtype=forest.classes_.dtype)
>         for k in range(forest.n_outputs_):
>             preds[:, k] = forest.classes_[k].take(modes[:, k], axis=0)
>         return preds
> ```
>
> On the dumb synthetic case I tried, predictions agreed with the
>   `predict` method every time.

Answer (score 1):

This was studied by Breiman in Bagging predictor (http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/421.pdf).

This gives nearly identical results, but using soft voting gives smoother probabilities. Note that if you are using completely developed tree, you won't have any difference.